# Can't debug WordPress with PhpStorm, WAMP & Virtual Hosts

Tags: phpstorm, wamp, xdebug, vhosts

Lots of possible setups and demos out there on the web, however I can't get the debugger to work (nothing happens!)

Windows setup

WAMP install:

```
C:\Wamp
```

Project folder:

```
"E:\Users\Rix\Offline Drive\Web Ghianda\Wordpress"
```

vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "E:\Users\Rix\Offline Drive\Web Ghianda\Wordpress"
    ServerName ghiandalocal.com
      <Directory "E:\Users\Rix\Offline Drive\Web Ghianda\Wordpress">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

PhpStorm configuration settings (tried also to change `127.0.0.1` to `ghiandalocal.com`):

[image]

PHP.ini Xdebug section

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=c:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.4\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.4-7.0-vc14.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1:81
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=0
xdebug.profiler_output_name=cachegrind.out.%s.%t
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.trace_output_dir="C:/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

PHPInfo: https://ibb.co/cmA5Lw

Comment: 1) `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1:81` -- where have you seen that? It must be an IP only. Xdebug does not care about your web server port, at all. 2) What URL do you use to browse your local site in a browser? is it `http://127.0.0.1/`? 3) Enable xdebug log and see what it has to say about such unsuccessful debug session.

Comment: To browse the site I use http://ghiandalocal.com

Comment: Added `xdebug.remote_log=c:/temp/xdebug.log` to php.ini, but no log is created when reloading web page

Comment: Tried to change `127.0.0.1` to `ghiandalocal.com` in `xdebug.remote_host=` and PHPStorm config. No change

Comment: 1) Create some file and call `phpinfo()` there -- show it's output -- top table (generic info) and then xdebug specific section. 2) xdebug must be created with your settings (`remote_autostart=1`) as xdebug should be attempting to debug every single request.

Comment: 3) Is your `ghiandalocal.com` resolves to `127.0.0.1`? What IP do you see when you run `ping ghiandalocal.com` in console?

Comment: Added PHPInfo link https://ibb.co/cmA5Lw; Ping will return 127.0.0.1

Comment: I think the wrong php.ini is being loaded! I'll check this and return ASAP

Comment: Quite possibly. 1) The xdebug is NOT enabled as per your screenshot (it's installed but `remote_enable` shows `Off`. 2) Older xdebug version is used there -- it's 2.4.0 while per your post it should be 2.5.4

Comment: Quite likely that you have edited php.ini that is used in CLI environment only. You may now need to do the same for the php.ini used by Apache.

Comment: Got it to work, would you like to post a reply on this? It was the wrong PHP.INI being loaded! I will select your post as the correct answer

Comment: You can post your own answer and then later accept it. Even though I gave you the hints I did not provide the exact reason myself.

Comment: Thanks :-) ............

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting Phpinfo, I have realised that PHP was loading php.ini from another folder, therefore no xdebug setting was being loaded.
Thanks to [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) for enlightening the route to the solution